# What happens when framebuffer is assigned a larger size than the swapchain images in vulkan driver?

Tags: driver, vulkan, framebuffer

I understand this does not respect the spec and warnings will pop from the validation layer, but I tested on my computer and the result seemed fine (basically rendering a larger image to the display vs making the swapchain and frambbuffer the same size)
I'm curious what does the driver do in this situation? Does the driver automatically shrink the framebuffer/render area/viewport to the size of the swapchain to avoid the unnecessary rendering work in the first place or a larger image will be rendered anyway and downscaled just before presented?

Comment: Not "warnings". ERRORs would pop up. Seems to be prohibited by `vkCreateFramebuffer` VUs saying an attachment **must** be same or bigger than framebuffer.

Answer (score 3):

The result of violating any valid usage rule is undefined behavior. And by definition, undefined behavior is... *undefined*. It could do *anything*. It could work. It could fail. It could work for a while then fail. It could open up a security hole to your OS that someone exploits 3 years from now.

What *precisely* happens is unknown; if it could be known, it would be *defined* behavior.